# Can you recycle slide/transparency/negative pages?

Tags: slides

I have several hundred used slide pages I want to dispose of. They're Print File, Vue All and Calumet brand. Are they recyclable? I called Print File and was told that some have polyethylene and others have polypropylene in them. My town's recycler told me to throw them in the trash. Any recycling leads appreciated, even if it means shipping them.

Comment: There's no practical use for the material in them on the recycle commodities market. We currently send more plastic (of the types that are easier to recycle) to be recycled than the demand for it. It may make you feel good to put that stuff in your recycle bin, but the net effect is that several tons of useable plastic that it gets thrown in with will probably wind up in a landfill because it is cost prohibitive for recyclers to sort it out from the stuff they could otherwise use. Why not try to sell them on eBay *as used slide holders*?

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to Recycle.

Post them for free on craigslist,

Contact local schools or universities that teach photography to see if they want them,

Join a Film Photography forum and see if any of the members there would like them.

Think outside the slide holder. Re-purpose them.

**Shelter in place OR Quarantine activity:**
Get some clear plastic sheet and cut it up into 2"x 2" squares and let your kids make drawings on them ( or just colored plastic squares and make a patern ) and then insert them into the slide holders and put them up in the window or make a lamp shade

[image: Photo from littlethings.com]

Photo from littlethings.com

Comment: Can i get a hallelujah ? "*It goes like this, the fourth, the fifth
The minor fall, the major lift*"